# How do I prevent Internet Explorer from enlarging my website?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, responsive-design, internet-explorer-10, magnify

I designed a responsive website, and Internet Explorer 10 (possibly earlier versions as well; no way to check) is doing something infuriating when the browser window gets 400px wide or narrower. It enlarges the entire site by about 25% (text, images, everything) and then ignores all media queries as you continue reducing the width of the window; it just scales everything down equally to fit.

I know this won't really be an issue in the wild, since nobody will be browsing a website on a desktop computer at 400px, and if they're using a mobile phone, they won't be using Internet Explorer, but it's driving me up the wall nonetheless. Is there a way to make it not do that?

Here's the site: www.rampartconstruction.net

Comment: With IE, you can press F12, and then choose a different Document Mode to determine what the page will look like in earlier versions of IE. FYI

Answer (score 0):

The div 'galleria-info' has a fixed width of 900px, not sure if this will be casuing this issue. But ideally should be 100%.